# Not sure where alias is coming from

Tags: macos, terminal, alias

When I open a terminal in MacOS (Monterey) and type alias I see a list of commands. for example

kr=kubectl

I do not see this defined in /Users/xxx/.zshrc file, I want to remove this alias and change it to something else but I'm not getting where is this defined.

I do not have .bashrc file in home dir.
I have .zshrc file but it does not have an alias in it.